# Unable to compile iOS Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin. I downloaded Xamarin and created one iOS sample project, however when I try to compile that project, it failed with following error:

> MTOUCH: error MT0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com
>           System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/usr/lib/mono/2.1' not found.

When I navigate to `/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions`, I cannot find `/usr/lib/mono/2.1` folder.
From where I can get this folder and why it is not present?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to restart the installer to check if anything is missing.

Comment: I have downloaded Xamarin.iOS 10.3.1, Xamarin.Mac 2.10.0 and Xamarin Workbooks & Inspector 1.0.0. What else I am missing?

Comment: only the installer knows. Don't attempt to manually download and install each components, as you can easily miss some.

Comment: If those three are really all you installed, you are missing Mono at least. Please try running the universal installer which can be downloaded here: https://www.xamarin.com/download-it?_bt=101035045148&_bk=xamarin%20download&_bm=e&gclid=Cj0KEQiAtqHEBRCNrdC6rYq9_oYBEiQAejvRl5CFkglTfdiY_lCiQ8JzXRMsGhyhguyuObg37kT4ix4aAu-u8P8HAQ#download . And the getting started guide may be helpful: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Xamarin.iOS and again ran universal installer, this time I installed everything, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Mac and Xamarin.iOS. Now it is working.

I am not sure, why I need to install everything when I am going to use only iOS?